# load local data files into hive table failed when using hive

Tags: hive

when i tried to load local data files into hive table,it report error while moving files.And i found the link,which give comments to fix this issue.I follow this step ,but it still can't work.

http://answers.mapr.com/questions/3565/getting-started-with-hive-load-the-data-from-sample-table txt-into-the-table-fails

After mkdir /user/hive/tmp,and set hive.exec.scratchdir= /user/hive/tmp,it still report RuntimeException Cannot make directory:file/user/hive/tmp/hive_2013* How can I fix this issue?Who are familiar with hive can help me?Thanks!

hive version is 0.10.0
hadoop version is 1.1.2

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a permission issue here, because you are using MapR distribution.

Make sure that the user trying to create the directory has permissions to create the directory on CLDB.

Easy way to debug here is to do
$hadoop fs -chmod -R 777 /user/hive 
and then try to load the data, to confirm if it's permission issue.